# Sorting an array by name in Powershell

Tags: arrays, sorting, powershell

I have a Problem with an Array in powershell. It consists "Name,Surname". The data is exported of an Active Directory, the Name,Surname is written in $Group.member.

I try to sort the Array by Name.

```
foreach($Member in $Members){
            $GMember += $Member.name  + " " +"("+ $Member.SamAccountname + ")" +"<br>"
            }

#now i like to sort

$GMember | sorty-by $Member.Name
```

Doesnt work.... any idea?
thanks for the Support!

Answer (score 3):

You're using strings, which is kind of horrible in itself (PowerShell is *much* happier with proper objects), but even then, your strings start with the name, so you can just sort them as they are:

```
$GMember | Sort-Object
```